# Timer is not upadating when app come Foreground to Background

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, timer

I try to run the countdown timer app.

When i came from Background to Forground,every time my timer start behind 1 second,

I got the system time when app run in background & get the diff between time when app come in forground with this code,

```
        NSDate *oldDate = [dateFor dateFromString:oldD];
        NSLog(@"Old Date in Timer : %@",oldDate);

        NSDate *newcurrentdate = [NSDate date];
        NSLog(@"NEWCURRENTDATE:%@",newcurrentdate);

        NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        NSUInteger unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit;
        NSDateComponents *componentsss = [gregorianCalendar components:unitFlags
                                                              fromDate:oldDate
                                                                toDate:newcurrentdate
                                                               options:0];
        [gregorianCalendar release];
```

With this i got diff. for particular sec when app come from background to foreground,

and add this sec to my timer code for update timer,

```
     ticks =ticks + 1;    
        if(ticks > 59)
        {
            minute = minute + 1;
            ticks = 0;
            if(minute > 59)
            {
                hour = hour + 1;
                minute = 0;
                if(hour > 23)
                {
                    hour = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

When time start first time it runs fine, but when coming from background to forground it timer start with one second behind every time,

I try to add 1 second in my code,but its not give particular timer value,

How can i do this?

Comment: How are you receiving "ticks"? Are you using NSTimer?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of counting ticks by incrementing a variable, would it be easier for you to get the difference between the current time and a start date using timeIntervalSinceNow or timeIntervalSinceDate?

To get minutes and hours from this interval on the fly, you could do the following:

```
minute = ((int) (ticks / 60)) % 60;
hour = ((int) (ticks / 3600)) % 24;
```

This should give much more accurate timings.